# What's the best way to find the index of a letter in a word with Python?

Tags: python, append, range

I want that the word I write return the correspondent number in my list.

So far I've made the list:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

word = input('word: ')
```

And this for separate each individual letter

```
list word= []

for i in range(len(word)):
    ListWord.append(word[i])
```

but I don't know were to go from here

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: Also `list word = []` is not valid python syntax. If you want  a list named `word`, just do  `word =  []`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution to your problem:

```py
word = input("word :")
output = [ord(x) - ord('a') for x in word]
```

The function `ord` returns the integer value associated to a charachter, e.g. `ord('a') = 97`. By subtracting the value of `ord('a')` from the `ord` of each char in the word you'll get the position of each char relative to the position of `a`. So `a` = 0, `b` = 1, ...

Comment: The example was just to use a one-liner and keep things simple. You can put `ord('a')` in a variable instead of computing it every time.

Comment: This is so neat. I  like how you avoided creating a new data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `index()` function on list.

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
word = input('word: ')

output = []
for letter in word:
    letter_number = list.index(letter) + 1
    output.append(str(letter_number))

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `list` as a variable name, it may override the built-in list.

You can also use `enumerate` with List comprehension.

```
word = input('word: ')
[(lttr,idx) for idx,lttr in enumerate(lst,1) for letter in word if letter == lttr]

word: mouse
[('e', 5), ('m', 13), ('o', 15), ('s', 19), ('u', 21)]
```